# Eclispelink PersistenceUnitLoadingException

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

i encountered `PersistenceUnitLoadingException` with Eclispelink 2.4.1 below, what do the stack traces tell?

[image: code window]

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-30005] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence archives with ClassLoader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@45a877
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-30005] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence archives with ClassLoader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@45a877
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException.exceptionSearchingForPersistenceResources(PersistenceUnitLoadingException.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:118)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown Source)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown Source)
    at com.mypkg.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:12)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-30005] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence archives with ClassLoader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@45a877
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException.exceptionSearchingForPersistenceResources(PersistenceUnitLoadingException.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.findPersistenceArchives(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.findPersistenceArchives(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.findPersistenceUnitInfoInArchives(JPAInitializer.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.findPersistenceUnitInfo(JPAInitializer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:76)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.DirectoryArchive.init(DirectoryArchive.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.DirectoryArchive.init(DirectoryArchive.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.DirectoryArchive.<init>(DirectoryArchive.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.DirectoryArchive.<init>(DirectoryArchive.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.ArchiveFactoryImpl.createArchive(ArchiveFactoryImpl.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.findPersistenceArchives(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:297)
    ... 7 more
Could not find the main class: com.mypkg.Main.  Program will exit.
```

**@EDIT**

i have the project structure under Eclipse below, which works well with Hibernate as the persistence provider.

```
bin
  |_META-INF
  |        |_persistence.xml
  |_com
      |_mypkg
            |_Main.class
            |_MyEntity.class
```

Comment: It would seem that it could not find a `persistence.xml` file.

Comment: i guess `persistence.xml` is well located and can be found by `Hibernate`. Could you check my update above? Thanks!

Comment: One of the elmements of a File.listFiles() call is null.  I have never seen this issue, but there are a few small code changes in EclipseLink 2.5 - can you give it a shot and post the stack trace to see if it changes?

Comment: What JVM/environment are you using?

Comment: Eclipse 3.7.2 with JDK 1.6.0_37 on Linux 3.2.0-33-generic-pae (32-bit Ubuntu 12.04.1)

Comment: A missing jar of your Hibernate library could make this exception!

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to eclipselink to the following resolved this issue for me:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>
```